# What is the level of math required needed by a Security Analyst?

Tags: professional-education

I have been learning Cyber and Information Security for a while now, from different sources and courses. While there is a lot of theory, no **high-level math** seems to appear anywhere, apart from **basic algebra** and the "**programming math**" (graph theory <not much of it, bit manipulation, binary operations, optimization, game theory, cryptography).

I came here to ask the experts, is there a **huge chapter** I'm missing, where high-school level math is needed, or is Cyber Analysis simply an application of the theory, definitions, scenarios, and predictions.

Comment: What type of Security Analyst? You tagged this with "cryptography", but that topic is not raised in your question. Are you talking about cryptographic analyst or a SOC analyst? There are different levels of knowledge required for different types of analysis.

Comment: This is a little like asking "how much knowledge of dermatology is required to be a doctor?" The answer depends on if you want to be a dermatologist or a psychologist...

Comment: Hello! I found out that Security Analyst is the name of a specialization in Information Security, so I thought it's like asking "how much dermatology is required to be a family doctor?"

Comment: "Security Analyst" is actually famously undefined. It can be a junior role doing a defined and focused set of tasks, or a senior role performing undefined sets of tasks across a broad range of knowledge. So, this question is not answerable. Math is good to train people in logic and problem solving. But a SOC analyst tends to need no more than basic high school math in their job. Other analyst types can require advanced math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Titles like "Security Analyst" are pretty vague; each company will have their own job requirements, and there is not as far as I know any standard per se. In practice, I've seen "security analyst" be a fancier-sounding version of "security engineer" (which encompasses everything from system design reviews to penetration testing to writing vulnerability detection tooling), I've seen it mean specifically somebody who reviews intrusion detection systems and other logging for signs of attacks, and I've seen it mean a compliance auditor for things like PCI DSS. I'm sure there are other meanings I haven't seen.

However, one thing that all the uses I've seen have in common is that higher math is basically irrelevant. Some of these tasks require being able to read and even write program source code and/or assembly, and some require a working knowledge of *applied* cryptography, but none require that you be able to implement any primitives and it's very rare to even see an implementation to review. I haven't professionally used my calculus, much less linear algebra, since graduation.

That said, the ability to think algorithmically and follow steps of logic is pretty important. Being able to compute time and space complexities can also help with things like noticing DoS risks. A bit of statistics can be useful when considering the likelihood of an attack, and trying to figure out where to set detection thresholds. None of this is typically taught in high school math (so far as I'm aware; some school systems might go into it). It doesn't require any more background that that, though (and possibly less).

Comment: Most *Security Analyst* are procedural, with a great many positions nothing more than *Check Box Enforcers*. There are other kinds of analysis that require more and deeper understanding. I often used an FFT to extract key information. Similarly *XOR* obfuscation and recovery is common. It can be important to understand the concepts and abilities to know that such techniques exist and when to use them. Admittedly this type of analysis is not the norm.

Comment: Thank you. This is the answer I was looking for. Thanks for the clarification.